# create a virtual COM port

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

i was trying to develop two c# .NET application that communicate with each other from a COM port.. the problem was in my laptop i don't have any serial device connected.. do i have any alternative approach to create a virtual comport from c#.net platform??
i tried from creating comport like this but it was not working..

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600);
            port.Open();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It’s 2015 and it is difficult to find PCs with COM port. Why don’t you use (W)LAN?

Comment: how ever that's what i want :) :)

Comment: Some time ago I had the same problem and I remember I installed a virtual COM port driver in Windows.  I think I used Windows 7 at that time. I just tried to do the same in Windows 8 but I did not find it. If you use Windows 7 or earlier try something like: Device Manager, right click on the top of the devices tree, add device… And then I think the driver which I installed was from Microsoft.
I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) software. It emulates com ports. Then you can connect your software to virtual com port and continue testing.

Answer (score -1):

I have been using Eterlogic VSPE for years! Very reliable! Works like a dream and you have many options. You can create virtual serial port pairs, multi splitter etc. I used it commercially also to read com communication from a closed source app to figure out a comms protocol to be able to write my own driver for it to communicate with my own hardware :) https://eterlogic.com/Downloads.html. It's free for non-commercial use

Comment: oh I am not in any way associated with Eterlogic, other than a very happy customer.